# Retrieve the attributes from a feature with IdentifyTask/IdentifyRequest (Javascript API)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, identify

So I'm building a GIS web application.  I am able to get the result from IdentifyTask with the "oncomplete" function, the problem I am running into is how I can get the information back out of the feature/attribute.  Here is the code that I am currently working with:

```
function onMapClick(evt) {
    var identifyParams = new esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
    identifyParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
    identifyParams.tolerance = 2;
    identifyParams.mapExtent = _Map.extent;
    var identify = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask(url);
    identify.execute(identifyParams);
    identify.on("complete", identifyCallBack);
    identify.on("error", showError);

}

function identifyCallBack(lotResults) {

    var out = [];
    var result = lotResults.results[0];
    var feature = result.feature;
    var attribute = feature.attributes;

    dojo.forEach(attribute, function(attr){
        out.push(attr);
    });
    alert(out.join(", "));

}

function showError(results) {

    alert(results.error.message);
}
```

Right now my identifyCallback is just coded trying to get the data I want.  Would it be easier to do a dojo.postback and pass the result back to my ASP.net form and parse up the data in Visual Studio?  If so how would I code the dojo.postback to return the value to a RadAjaxManager in Visual Studio?